# Create Pandas dataframe from 2 dataframes with calculated values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes with the following structure:

df1:

```
    HR POSDATETIME      MODEL  LAT    LON    WIND  PRES
4   0  2018-06-04 12:00  CARQ   105N   1016W  55    999
5   0  2018-06-04 18:00  CARQ   111N   1037W  65    997
6   0  2018-06-05 00:00  CARQ   117N   1035W  75    998
7   0  2018-06-05 06:00  CARQ   118N   1037W  72    996 
8   0  2018-06-05 12:00  CARQ   130N   1040W  80    997 
8   0  2018-06-05 18:00  CARQ   135N   1050W  65    999  
10  0  2018-06-06 00:00  CARQ   140N   1054W  70    997
```

df2:

```
    HR  POSDATETIME      MODEL LAT    LON     WIND PRES    
1   0  2018-06-04 12:00   CMC   112N   1023W   50   998   
2   0  2018-06-04 12:00   NGX   112N   1022W   55   999
3   6  2018-06-04 18:00   NGX   116N   1025W   70   997 
4  12  2018-06-05 00:00   NGX   125N   1022W   60   998
5  18  2018-06-05 06:00   NGX   131N   1024W   55   999
6  24  2018-06-05 12:00   NGX   137N   1030W   60   997
7  30  2018-06-05 18:00   NGX   141N   1039W   65   996
```

I need a resulting dataframe that has the following strucutre (output details made up):

```
HR  MODEL DISTERROR WINDERROR PRESERROR
0   CMC   15        5         1
etc.......
```

To get the output dataframe, I  would have to:

1. Compare all df2 data against the control data in df1.  The control data in df1 is the real data and the df2 data is a model guess.
2. I have a haversine algorithm to calculate the distance difference between the 2 lat/lon pairs (DISTERROR in resulting df).  The other two calculations are simply the absolute difference between values (easy enough).

The key factor is each position date/time has to equal before the calculation is done, with the result being calculated error values based on hour (HR).  Indicating how well the model is at guessing position, wind and pressure at each future hour (0, 6, 12, 24 etc...)

I know how to do this by brute force and looping through and doing calculations, but I was hoping pandas had a more elegant and efficient way.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    MILES = 3959
    lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = map(np.deg2rad, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    total_miles = MILES * c
    return total_miles
```

Comment: Are you comparing the two row-wise or based on some common column or combination of columns?

Comment: And for easier, there is package available of haversine in python, you can use it. More info. https://pypi.org/project/haversine/

Comment: @A.Leistra The POSDATETIME must match before a calculation so we are comparing the positions, winds, pressure for the same date/time

Comment: @user3280146 Thanks for the tip on the haversine package.  I did not know that.